# Prestashop - Calling categories api results in error

Tags: prestashop

I have to fetch data from a prestashop, and it has worked until now. They have upgraded their prestashop but haven't given me more details.

When I call: https://realshopname/api/categories?display=full&limit=0,50

which works fine on other prestashop installations and also this one, before they made an update. Now I get the following error

> PHP Warning #2] Declaration of Product::addAttribute($price, $weight,
> $unit_impact, $ecotax, $id_images, $reference, $delivery_label,
> $ean13, $default, $location = NULL, $upc = NULL, $minimal_quantity =
> 1, array $id_shop_list = Array, $available_date = NULL, $quantity = 0,
> $isbn = '', $low_stock_threshold = NULL, $low_stock_alert = false)
> should be compatible with ProductCore::addAttribute($price, $weight,
> $unit_impact, $ecotax, $id_images, $reference, $ean13, $default,
> $location = NULL, $upc = NULL, $minimal_quantity = 1, array
> $id_shop_list = Array, $available_date = NULL, $quantity = 0, $isbn =
> '', $low_stock_threshold = NULL, $low_stock_alert = false)
> (/var/www/realshopname/public_html/override/classes/Product.php, line
> 0)"

As far as I guess, the error is on their shop, but how can I help the shop in figuring out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to come because there is an override file (probably needed by some module to extend core functionalities) :

```
/var/www/realshopname/public_html/override/classes/Product.php
```

that conflicts with webservices.

Have an inspection on this file, you'll probably find in a comment the module that uses this override. Then check if module is still needed , in this case an update is required to make it compliant with new version. Otherwise uninstall the module and you should be all set.

Comment: Thank you, I'll reach out to them, to get them to take a look at that possibility :)